# How do I display a messagebox after an AccessViolationException is thrown

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, office-addins, access-violation

I would like to display a MessageBox whenever a **System.AccessViolationException** exception is thrown.

We have a VSTO Add-In that encounters an AccessViolationException Exception occasionally.

I've added the attributes [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]    and [SecurityCritical].  The exception is being caught.

Without the exception handler, Outlook restarts and logs the exception to the Application log (Event Viewer).

I would like to log the exception myself and put up a dialog letting users know that the system has become unstable and will need to be restarted manually (I have code to kill the Outlook process)

Throwing up a regular Modal Messagebox just hangs everything.  I guess I need to display a dialog in a separate thread; not sure how to do that.

```
[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
[SecurityCritical]
private void myInspector_Activate()
{
            
        
    try
    {
       // Crashing code
          
    }

    catch (System.AccessViolationException ex)
    {
        // write to log

        // THIS NEXT LINE JUST HANGS                     
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Hello There!");

       // THIS CLOSES OUTLOOK                                
       Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
               
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
         // Write to Log
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you get the access violation exception at runtime?

Comment: That's something we're still troubleshooting.   Outlook logs the exception in the Application log, but it doesn't give me the detail I'm looking for (e.g. line number of failing code)

Comment: What code do you have in the inspector `Activate` event? Do you have any other add-ins installed for Outlook? VBA?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev 
I would just like to know, in general, when an access violation is encountered, how can I alert the user.   Outlook simply closes and re-opens.   I would like to alert the user before Outlook closes without warning.   We've seen a Access violations for different reasons.

Comment: Have you ever seen such alerts in other software? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Inspector.Activate` fires on the main Outlook thread, so no reason to switch to the main thread to show a message box.

You really need to provide the user with the pdb file and log the exception call stack (`Exception.ToString()` will include it) to figure out where the exception occurs and fix it.

Comment: I'll be taking this approach.  Thanks.   It's the simplest, and most direct.

Answer (score 1):

Displaying any message boxes will stop the execution thread and may hang up the application further. Instead, I'd recommend on focusing on **fixing the issue** instead of letting the user know.

> I guess I need to display a dialog in a separate thread; not sure how to do that.

All UI-related things should be done on the main thread only. Sounds like you are going to delve into more series exceptions when displaying a dialog box after access violation exceptions took its place.

Consider displaying a message box to a user at startup of your add-in if you see any records with such information in the event viewer.

Comment: Fixing the issue is of course the main focus.  However, for this thread I'd still like to know how I could display a dialog (if possible).   I'm handling the cause of the exception with another group.

Comment: Displaying dialog may not be appropriate and possible in some cases. `AccessViolationException` is one of them.

Comment: Thanks!   I started to get that impression.